# Orden asintótico

Tags: algoritmos

tengo un problema para hacer un análisis del orden asintótico de un algoritmo de ordenamiento, este algoritmo usa buble sort para ordenar la mitad del arreglo y quick sort para la otra mitad, sabemos que buble sort es O(n^2) y que quick sort en el mejor de los casos es O(nlgn) entonces para este caso cual sería el orden para arreglar todo el arreglo.

Lo que he pensado yo es que seria de O(n^2/4+(n/2)lg(n/2)) en el mejor caso y O(n^2/2) en el peor de los casos.

Gracias por su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: ¿podrías ponerme un poco más en contexto? ¿Porque utiliza para una mitad del arreglo bubble sort? ¿Cuál es susodicho arreglo?

Comment: Bueno, estoy llevando la materia de algoritmos y nos piden que analicemos cual es el orden asintótico de emplear en un arreglo de enteros bubble sort para ordenar la mitad y Quicksort para la mitad restante, no se realmente porque esos dos, es un simple ejercicio que no pusieron